# Extract and append data to new datasets in a for loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, append

I have (what I think) is a really simple question, but I can't figure out how to do it.  I'm fairly new to lists, loops, etc.

I have a small dataset:

```
df <- c("one","two","three","four")
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df
```

I need to loop through this dataset and create a list of datasets, such that this is the outcome:

```
[[1]]
one

[[2]]
one
two

[[3]]
one
two
three
```

This is more or less as far as I've gotten:

```
blah <- list()

for(i in 1:3){
  blah[[i]]<- i
}
```

The length will be variable when I use this in the future, so I need to automate it in a loop.  Otherwise, I would just do

```
one <- df[1,]
two <- df[2,]

list(one, rbind(one, two))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `lapply` :

```
result <- lapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x) df[seq_len(x), , drop = FALSE])
result

#[[1]]
#   df
#1 one

# [[2]]
#   df
#1 one
#2 two

#[[3]]
#     df
#1   one
#2   two
#3 three

#[[4]]
#     df
#1   one
#2   two
#3 three
#4  four
```

`seq(nrow(df))` creates a sequence from 1 to number of rows in your data (which is 4 in this case). `function(x)` part is called as anonymous function where each value from 1 to 4 is passed to one by one. `seq_len(x)` creates a sequence from 1 to `x` i.e 1 to 1 in first iteration, 1 to 2 in second and so on. We use this sequence to subset the rows from dataframe (`df[seq_len(x), ]`). Since the dataframe has only 1 column when we subset it , it changes it to a vector. To avoid that we add `drop = FALSE`.

Comment: This works perfectly.  If I had one row from another dataframe that I wanted to bind to each of these lists, how could I do that? I'm currently using purrr::map(result,~rbind(.,row)) but I'm guessing there is a better way?

Comment: That is a good way or you can do it in the same `lapply`/`map` call. `result <- lapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x) rbind(df[seq_len(x), , drop = FALSE], row))`

Comment: Ah, perfect. I am just beginning to understand how lapply works. I tried added ,rbind(df,row) to the end of that function after FALSE], and it didn't work.  I think I'm starting to understand the functions better, now. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain why this function works: `function(x) df[seq_len(x), , drop = FALSE]`?

Comment: I added some explanation on how the code works. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I absolutely could not have figured that out. Your solution is so eloquent and I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Coerce df vector of data.frame to character, store as new data.frame: str_df => data.frame 
str_df <- transform(df, df = as.character(df))

# Allocate some memory in order to split data into a list:  df_list => empty list
df_list <- vector("list", nrow(str_df))

# Split the string version of the data.frame into a list as required: 
# df_list => list of character vectors
df_list <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(str_df)), function(i){
    str_df[if(i == 1){1}else{1:i}, grep("df", names(str_df))]
  }
)
```

Data:

```
df <- c("one","two","three","four")
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df
```

Comment: I actually am struggling a bit since my data is more complicated than one, two, three.  For example, one of the rows of data includes "x+y=2".  When I transform it to "as character", it's concatenating in a weird way, e.g. "c(\"x+y=2\", \"x+y=3\")".

Comment: Nevermind, just needed to select the variable name, e.g., df$V1. THANK YOU!

Comment: @missgwolf no worries, please accept my answer if it has done what you require !